# How to fix error in checkout page after upgrading Magento2.4.3-p3

Tags: checkout, payment, magento2.4.3

I got this error
[image]
so checkout is not working.

**= UPDATE =**
[image]
[image]

**= UPDATE =**

And I got error like this.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "afterRender: function(){return renderReCaptcha() }"
Message: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'rendering')
    at UiClass.initCaptcha (reCaptcha.js:117:35)
    at UiClass.renderReCaptcha (reCaptcha.js:182:26)
    at afterRender (eval at createBindingsStringEvaluator (knockout.js:3221:28), <anonymous>:3:134)
    at init (after-render.js:17:28)
    at knockout.js:3730:58
    at Object.ignore (knockout.js:1563:45)
    at knockout.js:3729:60
    at Object.arrayForEach (knockout.js:168:36)
    at applyBindingsToNodeInternal (knockout.js:3715:34)
    at applyBindingsToNodeAndDescendantsInternal (knockout.js:3573:56)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check if your customize code in modules/theme or 3rd-party extensions/theme overrides Magento_Checkout then apply the changes from Magento 2.4.3 to these files.

Check if after run `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f` static content files are generated into `pub/static` or not.

To fix issue "JS error in console on checkout when recaptcha for checkout/placing order is not enabled" apply the following patch.

```
diff --git a/vendor/magento/module-re-captcha-checkout/Block/LayoutProcessor/Checkout/Onepage.php b/vendor/magento/module-re-captcha-checkout/Block/LayoutProcessor/Checkout/Onepage.php
index 3ee2rd..8349152 111644
--- a/vendor/magento/module-re-captcha-checkout/Block/LayoutProcessor/Checkout/Onepage.php
+++ b/vendor/magento/module-re-captcha-checkout/Block/LayoutProcessor/Checkout/Onepage.php
@@ -79,7 +79,8 @@
             ['place-order-recaptcha']['settings'] = $this->captchaUiConfigResolver->get($key);
         } else {
             if (isset($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
-                ['payment']['children']['beforeMethods']['children']['place-order-recaptcha'])) {
+                ['payment']['children']['beforeMethods']['children']['place-order-recaptcha-container']['children']
+                ['place-order-recaptcha'])) {
                 unset($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
                     ['payment']['children']['beforeMethods']['children']['place-order-recaptcha-container']
                     ['children']['place-order-recaptcha']);
```

Comment: should I use Klarna in Magento2.4.3?

Comment: To mitigate this issue immediately, I  disabled the Klarna logs by setting logging to disabled at Stores -> Settings -> Configuration -> Sales -> Payment Methods -> Klarna -> Configure -> API configuration -> Request Logging. But site is not loading yet. And I think have to change requir-config.js file, is right?

Comment: To try apply the patch, I made patch file in vendor/Klarna and then paste code in it.
Then git apply klarna_logs.patch but got error "error: corrupt patch at line 25"

Comment: If you do not use Klarna, you don't need to apply this patch. **Check if your customize code** in modules/theme or 3rd-party extension/theme overrides Magento_Checkout then **apply the changes from Magento 2.4.3 to these files**. You can get the code for Magento_Checkout in `vendor/magento/module-checkout` or from github: https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/2.4.3-p3/app/code/Magento/Checkout/

Comment: Hi @Tu van what is the pub/stactic directory. I found no file in pub/stactic. I run command "php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f" ago, but there is no file.
so I think this checkout has errors because of this. May I move stact/js files from old to new.

Comment: Great! Looks like this caused the issue. **pub/static** contains **generated** static view files. You should not copy the old files to there because it will be removed after every bin/magento setup:upgrade command. You should check permission for that folder to make sure bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy command able to generating static view files.

Comment: ok. I run command "php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f" and then "php bin/magento setup:upgrade"

Comment: No, you should change the sort order of these commands because after running `bin/magento setup:upgrade` the generated static view files (static content) generated by `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` will be removed. So run `bin/magento setup:upgrade` first, then run`bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f` after that.

Comment: thanks @Tu Van. And I got other errors.
so I added error in post

Comment: @BohdanV. I've updated my answer with the fix for your new issue related to ReCaptcha. If you don't know how to apply the patch, take a look at this document: https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/upgrade-guide/patches/apply.html#composer